# Facebook Login iOS SDK stuck at "Confirm"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

Is anyone experiencing this issue? After pressing login button and starting the process, the user will be stuck at this screen, where you should enable or confirm permissions for the application. However, there's nothing to do here.

[Screenshot from iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaHdB.png)

Comment: I'm currently having the exact same issue on my app! I first thought it was the fault of the cordova plugin I'm using but seeing you're native I feel like Facebook are the one to blame.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, cant find anything ,surely something going wrong @ facebook this is happening in live running apps also (Only IOS),android apps working fine.

Comment: Looks like the issue has been fixed according to this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/180459832419216/?comment_id=619998781505655

Answer (score 0):

```
In appdelegate:

import FacebookCore

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                                     open: url,
                                                     sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                     annotation: annotation)
}


@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, options: options)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    AppEventsLogger.activate(application)
}


In View Controller

import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin


func facebookLogin() {
    let loginManager = LoginManager()
    loginManager.logIn([ .email ], viewController: self) { (loginResult) in
        switch loginResult {
        case .failed(let error):
            print(error)
        case .cancelled:
            print("User cancelled login.")
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
            print("Logged in \(grantedPermissions) \(declinedPermissions) \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
}

And if you have multiple social login like facebook login and google signin

func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

    var _: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue: sourceApplication as AnyObject,
                                        UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue: annotation as AnyObject]

    if url.absoluteString.contains("facebook") {
        return SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,
                                                         open: url,
                                                         sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                         annotation: annotation)
    }else{
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL!,
                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                annotation: annotation)
    }
}
```

The above edit to should work.

Source:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/blob/master/Samples/Catalog/Sources/AppDelegate.swift